# CruiseControl cannot get web interface to work

Tags: java, web-services, cruisecontrol

On a fresh installation of CruiseControl, every single time I start CruiseControl, I get the following two exceptions thrown:

```
ontrollerAgent- Exception starting httpAdaptor
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)

ontrollerAgent- Exception starting connectorServer
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [jrmp]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jrmp [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(Unknown Source)
```

Before and after these nothing seems to (obviously) go wrong. And as a result, I cannot view the web dashboard of CruiseControl. Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

---

Full stack traces:

```
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- Starting HttpAdaptor with CC-Stylesheets
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- starting httpAdaptor
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- Exception starting httpAdaptor
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at mx4j.tools.adaptor.PlainAdaptorServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket (PlainAdaptorServerSocketFactory.java:24)
        at mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.HttpAdaptor.createServerSocket(HttpAdaptor.java:672)
        at mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.HttpAdaptor.start(HttpAdaptor.java:478)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.jmx.CruiseControlControllerAgent.start(CruiseControlControllerAgent.java:172)
        [truncated]

[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- starting rmiRegistry
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- Port 1099 is already in use, so no new rmiRe
gistry is started
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- starting connectorServer
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:50 ontrollerAgent- Exception starting connectorServer
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [jrmp]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jrmp [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.jmx.CruiseControlControllerAgent.start(CruiseControlControllerAgent.java:190)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.startJmxAgent(Main.java:137)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.start(Main.java:115)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:259)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:117)

Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jrmp [Root exception is java.
rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        [truncated]
2010-02-25 16:33:50.710::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2010-02-25 16:33:50.850::INFO:  jetty-6.1.11
2010-02-25 16:33:51.161:/dashboard:INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Which version of CC, which installer used, which OS?

Comment: CC 2.8.3, using the Windows binary installer CruiseControl-2.8.3.exe, installed on Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any Java program still running at the time of CC starting?

As illustrated in [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Every-morning-jvm_bind-Exceptin-in-Cruise-control-td20103838.html):

> I've noticed when I restart cruisecontrol  I need to kill any remaining java programs or a port class error will occur.
>   The solution is to:
>
> - Stop cruisecontrol
> - Kill any remaining cvs and java programs.
> - Wait 30 seconds.
> - Start cruisecontrol.

---

The OP [bguiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194982/bguiz) adds in the comments his own recipe:

> - Stop CruiseControl
> - Kill any remaining cvs and java programs.
> - Restart computer,
> - sc delete CruiseControl,
> - wrapper -i wrapper.conf.
> - Start CruiseControl

Comment: Thanks @VonC! Not quite the answer, but was on the right track --> basically replace `Wait 30 seconds.` with: [Restart computer, `sc delete CruiseControl`, `wrapper -i wrapper.conf`] and that worked for me.

Comment: @bguiz: thank you for the feedback. I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have another application server running on your machine that uses the same ports as your cruise control server.
Do you deploy Cruise Control on a new server? What server is it?

Try to stop all the servers on your machine and try to launch cruise control again.

Comment: @Awano, thanks for the answer! I know that what it looks like from the error message, but this was a fresh install of Win XP, and I am 100% positive no other software was utilising any of the ports, so it had to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the windows service wrapper to launch CruiseControl, the RMI port is set to 1099 by default. You can alter this port by editing the wrapper.conf file in your CruiseControl installation directory. You might want to run 'netstat' at a command prompt to list all the ports your system is currently using. Then pick one that doesn't conflict with any other server or process.
Killing all other processes isn't always an option.